# How to avoid expand table attributes?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create table, and render data which i have received from API, my html css looks like this:

```
///html
<section id="Characters">
    <table id="customers">
      <tr>
        <th><strong>Category</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Nickname</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Work</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Image</strong></th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </section>
//css
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

  width: 200%;
}


#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

Problem is , when i am receiving data for example  `<th><strong>Name</strong></th>` in this attribut, this attribute expands, and getting large, is there any elegant way to solve this problem, I tried

```
tr td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
} and tr   td {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

but this does not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#customers {
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   width: 60%;
   table-layout: fixed; /* <- add this */
}

tr td {
   width: 10%; /* You can custom the width as you need */
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

See if it works ;D

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
table{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
td {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fixing table layout and giving it a width could fix that. Try this

```
table{ table-layout:fixed; width: 1000px;}
```